# Convert Current date with Current date -1

Tags: bash

How to change the CURRENT Date with CURRENT Date -1 all records in a file.

Example below.

Input

```
HEADER2014-05-040000000002
2014-05-04|123456789
2014-05-04|987654321
```

Expected Output

```
HEADER2014-05-030000000002
2014-05-03|123456789
2014-05-03|987654321
```

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: Is your header line consistent in format? Do you actually have `HEADER` or is that a placeholder for variable length of characters?

Comment: Header date will also change based the run date. I have tried with sed but it didn't work.

Comment: sed "s/\([0-9]*\-\$(date -d "-1 day" +%Y%m%d)/$(date +%Y%m%d)/" file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `head -n1` to get the first line, `tail -n+2` to get everything except the first line, `awk '{print $n}'`  to print the nth column, and `date --date="$my_date - 1"` to get the previous date.